# How to do http redirect before Angular app initialized?

Tags: angular, redirect

I'm using APP_INITIALIZER in app.module.ts and calling function initApp. Is it possible to redirect to external page before any angular content is rendered? Something like this, but it's not working as expected:

```
export function initApp() {
  return () => {
    if (condition) {
      window.location.href = 'https://domain';
    }
  };
}
```

Redirection is working, but after the content is rendered.

Comment: This should return a function that returns a Promise. As long as the promise is not resolved, the app doesn’t load..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MikeOne's comment is already enough but if you need further help, follow [this](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-how-to-use-app-initializer/), which exactly matches with your need and thoroughly explains every steps with sample code snippets.

Comment: Thank you BDB and MikeOne. Promise => reject() did the trick.